# includepdf is not working on a computer but is working fine on another

Tags: pdftex

I have a strange error when trying to include a pdf file on a document that is appearing only on my laptop. Here is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\begin{document}
\includepdf{publications.pdf}
\end{document}
```

At the compilation, I get 3 main errors :

- undefined control sequence includepdf
- missing number treated as zero
- illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)

When I look at the output pdf anyway, I get the good result except that, at the top of the page, "=210mm =297mm" is inserted.

Now I have to precise that I'm using pdflatex for the compilation and that this code works perfectly well on my other computer, which drives me a bit confused.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try ``\includepdf{pages=-}{publications.pdf}``. And make sure that path to the PDF is the same as on the other computer.

Comment: Check in the log-files where pdfpages.sty comes from and which version it is.

Comment: Same errors. The path is the same, I'm working with dropbox.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike! A local copy of pdfpages was in my current directory. I deleted it, and now everything's working perfectly well :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a stray file in the OP's system